# Laravel package error on file uploading using Spatie\MediaLibrary

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-medialibrary

i just try to upload the image to the server using Spatie\MediaLibrary package .Then laravel gives this error of not found function. I tried all the solution no one worked

> This is the code that i am using

```
> public function update(Request $request, Channel $channel)
>     {
>        if($request->hasFile("image")){
>          $channel->addAllMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images');
>        }
>     }
```

[image: please click here to see the error message]

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use \YouTube\Model;
use App\User;

class Channel extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

> this is my model

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @AMC i will be take care for it in future.Thanks for the guideline .i understand image posting is not the good way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addAllMediaFromRequest()` method returns a collection of newly added media.

You need to iterate through each added file to add it to the collection.

```php
$channel->addAllMediaFromRequest('image')
    ->each(function ($fileAdder) {
        $fileAdder->toMediaCollection('images');
    });
```

Comment: but how do you know about this?

Comment: i am new in laravel so

Comment: It's in the Spatie documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is very obvious saying that it cant find the model that you have in use statement `use \YouTube\Model;`. You should really be importing the laravel model. i.e.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Comment: no actually have created my own basemodel which is extending to the eloquent model

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Model extends BaseModel
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $guarded = [];

Comment: and where is that base model, where is this `\Youtube\Model` coming from ???

Comment: no actually i changed the application name . so youtube referring to app directory. so the base model in app/model